# How to find out how advanced a hospital is for a specific speciality

Tags: surgery, vision

I need to have cataract surgery and I have some options (indirectly) of where the surgery will be performed.

Based on my medical coverage, I actually have a choice of a few doctors, and each doctor is affiliated with particular hospitals, so when I choose the doctor, I will indirectly choose which hospitals the surgery will be performed at (in theory).

Now, as surgeries go, and even surgeries related to vision, cataract surgery is probably an a fairly low level of complexity, and most any modern hospital that performs vision surgeries, would likely be equipped to handle such a surgery. But, I am more concerned about their ability to handle any complications that might arise during the surgery.

By "how advanced a hospital is", I'm talking relative to the equipment the hospital has available, and the training and experience of the staff, for a specific surgical procedure, and the ability to handle any possible or likely complications related to that surgery.

So, for a particular hospital (and even a particular doctor), how can I find out if they are suitable for the procedure? (I suppose it mostly relates to qualifications, reputation, and experience).

I could ask the doctor or the hospital, but I assume their opinions would be biased.

Answer (score 2):

You might try the [Consumer Reports](http://www.consumerreports.org/health/doctors-hospitals/hospital-ratings.htm) online tool that allows you to select and compare hospitals, evaluated for safety and infection rates.

Another useful site is the [Hospital Safety Score](http://www.hospitalsafetyscore.org/), a public service of a non-profit organization, that lets you see an overall score, as well as more specific ratings regarding surgery, practices, safety, and clinicians.